# MYSQL Stored Procedure failed on second run

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure to create a roster table. Source is a view which collects the needed data. The stored procedure should prepare the data to be displayed to the team. Either for a specific team member or an overview for all. When I call the procedure the first time anything is fine and I receive the data as expected. But on the second run with a different parameter it fails with an error 'SQL Error [1054] [42S22]: (conn:218) Unknown column 'd0294220.duties.TM 3' in 'field list' Query is : call somp_roster('Ritchie')'

The missing column depends on the parameter in the first run.

The view collects the data from 4 tables:

```
CREATE VIEW somv_roster AS
SELECT bd.businessday AS Datum,
v.venue AS Dropzone,
d.duty AS Service,
c.nickname AS Staff
FROM som_roster r
INNER JOIN som_businessday bd ON bd.businessdayID = r.ID_businessday
INNER JOIN som_venue v ON v.venueID = bd.ID_venue
INNER JOIN som_duty d ON d.dutyID = r.ID_duty
INNER JOIN som_contact c ON c.contactID = r.ID_contact
ORDER BY bd.businessday, v.venue
WHERE bd.businessday >= CURDATE();
```

Result looks like this:

```
Datum       Dropzone    Service     Staff
2018-04-28  Illertissen TM 2        Manu
2018-04-28  Illertissen Packer      Martina B.
2018-04-28  Illertissen TM 1        Rued
2018-04-28  Illertissen TM 3        Hane
2018-04-29  Illertissen Manifest    Sissi
2018-04-29  Illertissen TM 2        Ritchie
2018-04-29  Illertissen Packer      Martina B.
2018-04-29  Illertissen TM 1        Rued
2018-04-29  Illertissen TM 3        Hane
2018-05-01  Illertissen TM 1        Ritchie
2018-05-01  Illertissen TM 3        Hane
2018-05-01  Illertissen TM 2        Purzl
2018-05-01  Illertissen Packer      Martina B.
2018-05-26  Illertissen TM 1        Rued
2018-05-26  Kempten     TM 1        Ritchie
2018-05-26  Kempten     TM 2        Hane
2018-05-26  Kempten     Manifest    Sissi
```

Now I'm going to build a new table which should show this:

```
Datum       Dropzone    Manifest    Packer      TM 1    TM 2    TM 3
2018-04-28  Illertissen [NULL]      Martina B.  Rued    Manu    Hane
2018-04-29  Illertissen Sissi       Martina B.  Rued    Ritchie Hane
2018-05-01  Illertissen [NULL]      Martina B.  Ritchie Purzl   Hane
2018-05-26  Illertissen [NULL]      [NULL]      Rued    [NULL]  [NULL]
2018-05-26  Kempten     Sissi       [NULL]      Ritchie Hane    [NULL]
```

Or for a specific team member it should look like this:

```
Datum       Dropzone    TM 2    TM 3
2018-04-28  Illertissen [NULL]  Hane
2018-04-29  Illertissen [NULL]  Hane
2018-05-01  Illertissen [NULL]  Hane
2018-05-26  Kempten     Hane    [NULL]
```

In the stored procedure I define a cursor and loop through that cursor. In a temp table I add the results and display the table at the end.

The stored procedure:

```
    /*
 * Create routine somp_roster()
 * Requires somp_roster_et() to expand the columns dynamically.
 * Requires somv_roster view to read the rosters.
 * 4Air 2018 (c)
 */

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS somp_roster;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE somp_roster(IN staff_name VARCHAR(25))
BEGIN
    /*
     *  variables have to be declared at the start of the procedure
     *  declare variables for the loops
     *  flag to be set at the end of the loop
     */
    DECLARE finishedloop INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

    -- flag to loop through the duty table to
    DECLARE temp_date DATE DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE temp_venue VARCHAR(25) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE temp_duty VARCHAR(25) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE temp_staff VARCHAR(25) DEFAULT '';

    -- this var holds the string for the alter table statement
    DECLARE alttable VARCHAR(250) DEFAULT '';

    -- the first cursor to prepare the temp table
    DECLARE roster_cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT * FROM somv_roster WHERE Datum >= CURDATE() AND Staff LIKE CONCAT('%',staff_name) ORDER BY Service;    

    -- to recognize the end of the loops. Set to 0 before starting the loop!
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finishedloop = 1;

    -- cleanup first from a interrupted previous run
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS duties;

    -- now we need a temp table for the duties
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE duties (Datum DATE, Dropzone VARCHAR(25), PRIMARY KEY(Datum, Dropzone)) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;

    -- loop through the temp table
    SET finishedloop = 0;
    OPEN roster_cursor;
    SET @alttable = '';

    get_roster_loop: LOOP

        -- now read the duties and create the new rows in the temp rosters
        FETCH roster_cursor INTO temp_date, temp_venue, temp_duty, temp_staff;
        IF finishedloop = 1 THEN
            LEAVE get_roster_loop;
        END IF;

        /*
         * fist step - try to expand the table with needed column
         * the statement has to be this:
         * call somp_rosters_et('tablename','columnname','columndefs')
         * example:
         * CALL somp_rosters_et('duties','TM 1','VARCHAR(25)');
         */

        CALL somp_roster_et('duties',temp_duty,'VARCHAR(25)');

        /*
         * next prepare the statement to fill the data...
         * implies the test if the date and venue already exists
         * if so, then use UPDATE TABLE rather then INSERT TABLE
         */
        SET @alttable = CONCAT('INSERT INTO duties (`Datum`,`Dropzone`,`', temp_duty , '`) VALUES (''' , temp_date , ''',''' , temp_venue , ''',''' , temp_staff , ''') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `', temp_duty , '` = ''', temp_staff , ''';') ;
        PREPARE stmt FROM @alttable;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;


    END LOOP get_roster_loop;

    CLOSE roster_cursor;

    SELECT * FROM duties ORDER BY Datum, Dropzone;

    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS duties;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

The second stored procedure to add the needed column to the temp table:
I build this to have an second handler for the sql exception when I try to add an existing column.

```
   /*
 * Stored Procedure to expand the table and do not care about an error if the column exists.
 * Used by somp_roster();
 * 4Air 2018 (c).
 */

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS somp_roster_et;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE somp_roster_et(IN t_name VARCHAR(25), IN c_name VARCHAR(25), IN c_attribute VARCHAR(25))
BEGIN
    DECLARE eflag INTEGER DEFAULT 0; 
    DECLARE modtable VARCHAR(150) DEFAULT "";
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET eflag = 1;
    SET @modtable = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ' , t_name , ' ADD COLUMN `' , c_name , '` ' , c_attribute , ';');
    -- INSERT INTO som_log (Entry) VALUES(CONCAT('somp_roster_et: ',@modtable));
    PREPARE stmt FROM @modtable;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

This works for the first run. On the second run with a different team member as a parameter for the first procedure the SELECT statement at the end of the procedure throws an error:

SQL Error [1054] [42S22]: (conn:218) Unknown column 'd0294220.duties.TM 3' in 'field list' Query is : call somp_roster('Ritchie')

When I remove the last SELECT from the procedure and also remove the drop table command I can receive the data manually:

```
call somp_roster('Ritchie');
SELECT * FROM duties;
call somp_roster('Martina B.');
SELECT * FROM duties;
```

This works fine. Why do I get the exception when I select the data inside the procedure?

Richard

2018-dec-04

Still fighting with this... I've changed the procedure a bit but the strange behavior is still present.

New procedure:

```
/*
 * Create routine somp_roster()
 *
 * 2018-02-15 / implement a second handler for sql exceptions to handle the expand and select in this script
 * 
 * somp_roster_et is depricated with this change.
 * 
 * Requires somv_roster view to read the rosters.
 * 4Air 2018 (c)
 */

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS somp_roster;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE somp_roster(IN staff_name VARCHAR(25))
BEGIN
    /*
     *  variables have to be declared at the start of the procedure
     *  declare variables for the loops
     *  flag to be set at the end of the loop
     */
    DECLARE finishedloop,eflag, loopcount INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

    -- flag to loop through the duty table to
    DECLARE temp_date DATE DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE temp_venue, temp_duty, temp_staff VARCHAR(25) DEFAULT '';

    -- this var holds the string for the alter table statement
    DECLARE alttable,modtable VARCHAR(250) DEFAULT '';

    -- the first cursor to prepare the temp table
    DECLARE roster_cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT * FROM somv_roster WHERE date >= CURDATE() AND staff LIKE CONCAT('%',staff_name) ORDER BY service;    

    -- to recognize the end of the loops. Set to 0 before starting the loop!
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finishedloop = 1;

    -- to recognize a sql exception and continue
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET eflag = 1;

    -- cleanup first from a interrupted previous run
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS duties;

    -- now we need a temp table for the duties
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE duties (Datum DATE, Dropzone VARCHAR(25), PRIMARY KEY(Datum, Dropzone)) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;

    -- loop through the temp table
    SET finishedloop = 0;
    OPEN roster_cursor;
      SET @alttable = '';

    get_roster_loop: LOOP

        -- now read the duties and create the new rows in the temp rosters
        FETCH roster_cursor INTO temp_date, temp_venue, temp_duty, temp_staff;
        IF finishedloop = 1 THEN
          LEAVE get_roster_loop;
        END IF;

        SET @modtable = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE duties ADD COLUMN `' , temp_duty , '` VARCHAR(25);');
        PREPARE stmt FROM @modtable;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

        /*
         * next prepare the statement to fill the data...
         * implies the test if the date and venue already exists
         * if so, then use UPDATE TABLE rather then INSERT TABLE
         */
        SET @alttable = CONCAT('INSERT INTO duties (`Datum`,`Dropzone`,`', temp_duty , '`) VALUES (''' , temp_date , ''',''' , temp_venue , ''',''' , temp_staff , ''') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `', temp_duty , '` = ''', temp_staff , ''';') ;

        PREPARE stmt FROM @alttable;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    END LOOP get_roster_loop;
    CLOSE roster_cursor;
    SELECT * FROM duties ORDER BY Datum, Dropzone;
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS duties;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Now I changed the temporary table to a persistent INNODB table to see what the procedure creates and this is always the result I expect. Now I change the SELECT statement at the end to this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM duties;
```

and I always get the correct count.

Any ideas what is the reason for this?

Richard

Comment: Wrong copy and paste on the view... the WHERE clause is before the ORDER BY...

Comment: I changed the procedure to handle all the stuff in one part after I figured out that I can use two handlers with different conditions. But the error at the end of the script is still there.

Comment: Can  you leave a sample data on sqlfiddle?

Comment: I tried it but I was not able to add the procedure to sqlfiddle. Also I figured out, that it depends on the db config. My dev db is a MariaDB and the production is on Mysql. On the production side it runs well but on the dev side the strange behaviour is there.

Comment: Just put the tables, with sample data... I will test the stored procedures on my own..

Comment: @Ivan Cachicatari Unfortunately its a bit extensive to put the tables and views for the procedure. I'm still fighting with this. I changed the procedure to return the count of the found entries and on another try I switched the temporary table to be persistent and with the INNODB engine. So I can see what the procedure creates and this is correct. So its only the last statement which is failing.